# Python Consistently Crashes after ~2 minutes of running

Tags: python, opencv, crash

I've been working on OpenCV for gesture detection, and a few days ago python just randomly started crashing. It happens about 2 minutes after I start running the app, and I don't really know why. Can anyone help?

```
2016-06-11 22:28:23.294 python[1991:273050] -[CaptureDelegate doFireTimer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fec7bd0aa90
2016-06-11 22:28:23.296 python[1991:273050] An uncaught exception was raised
2016-06-11 22:28:23.296 python[1991:273050] -[CaptureDelegate doFireTimer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fec7bd0aa90
2016-06-11 22:28:23.296 python[1991:273050] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff868574f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8ff34f7e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff868c11ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867c7571 ___forwarding___ + 1009
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867c70f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff97405dec __NSFireTimer + 95
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867d4b94 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867d4823 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1075
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867d437a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 298
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867cb871 __CFRunLoopRun + 1841
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867caed8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    11  Foundation                          0x00007fff97380ed9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 270
    12  Foundation                          0x00007fff97414fc3 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 108
    13  libopencv_videoio.3.1.dylib         0x0000000101fc9d11 _ZN12CvCaptureCAM9grabFrameEd + 241
    14  libopencv_videoio.3.1.dylib         0x0000000101fbda8f _ZN2cv12VideoCapture4grabEv + 31
    15  libopencv_videoio.3.1.dylib         0x0000000101fbde13 _ZN2cv12VideoCapture4readERKNS_12_OutputArrayE + 19
    16  cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so           0x0000000100a9546f _ZL29pyopencv_cv_VideoCapture_readP7_objectS0_S0_ + 367
    17  Python                              0x00000001003fdfbe PyCFunction_Call + 60
    18  Python                              0x0000000100463ca9 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 23725
    19  Python                              0x00000001004673fc _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1949
    20  Python                              0x000000010045df93 PyEval_EvalCode + 75
    21  Python                              0x00000001004851ae run_mod + 58
    22  Python                              0x00000001004854cd PyRun_FileExFlags + 178
    23  Python                              0x0000000100484b5c PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 676
    24  Python                              0x0000000100499255 Py_Main + 3365
    25  python                              0x00000001003b7e3d python + 7741
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8f8cf5ad start + 1
)
2016-06-11 22:28:23.296 python[1991:273050] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CaptureDelegate doFireTimer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fec7bd0aa90'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff868574f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8ff34f7e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff868c11ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867c7571 ___forwarding___ + 1009
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867c70f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff97405dec __NSFireTimer + 95
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867d4b94 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867d4823 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1075
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867d437a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 298
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867cb871 __CFRunLoopRun + 1841
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff867caed8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    11  Foundation                          0x00007fff97380ed9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 270
    12  Foundation                          0x00007fff97414fc3 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 108
    13  libopencv_videoio.3.1.dylib         0x0000000101fc9d11 _ZN12CvCaptureCAM9grabFrameEd + 241
    14  libopencv_videoio.3.1.dylib         0x0000000101fbda8f _ZN2cv12VideoCapture4grabEv + 31
    15  libopencv_videoio.3.1.dylib         0x0000000101fbde13 _ZN2cv12VideoCapture4readERKNS_12_OutputArrayE + 19
    16  cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so           0x0000000100a9546f _ZL29pyopencv_cv_VideoCapture_readP7_objectS0_S0_ + 367
    17  Python                              0x00000001003fdfbe PyCFunction_Call + 60
    18  Python                              0x0000000100463ca9 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 23725
    19  Python                              0x00000001004673fc _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1949
    20  Python                              0x000000010045df93 PyEval_EvalCode + 75
    21  Python                              0x00000001004851ae run_mod + 58
    22  Python                              0x00000001004854cd PyRun_FileExFlags + 178
    23  Python                              0x0000000100484b5c PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 676
    24  Python                              0x0000000100499255 Py_Main + 3365
    25  python                              0x00000001003b7e3d python + 7741
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8f8cf5ad start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Are you by chance using `waitKey`? https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5874 What version of OpenCV are you using? I suggest trying 3.0 if you're using 3.1

Comment: I was in a different program, but in the one I'm working on right now I haven't used waitKey yet...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664448/brew-downgrade-formula-to-previous-version-opencv3-3-0-0-on-mac-el-capitan supports the idea of trying an earlier version of OpenCV

Comment: Do you happen to know of any way to fix this problem besides downgrading? That is like a last resort option. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the program was working correctly until recently. Then it started working incorrectly. This implies that the program was changed. The most likely change is a modification to your Python script that interfaces with OpenCV. I would remove parts of the Python script until the program does not crash. Then I would gradually add parts back until I had a minimal script that crashes. People on stackoverflow might be able to make suggestions about that minimal script.

Comment: I just started a new project today, without using waitKey, and I am still experiencing this same error. The code I have is taking a frame from a video, converting it to grayscale, blurring it and then applying a threshold.